# Continous function from $ \Bbb Q \rightarrow \Bbb R $, $ f = 1 $ for $x > \sqrt2$ and $ f = 0$ for $x < \sqrt2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers

I'm not really sure how to go about this problem.

Show that $h : \Bbb Q \rightarrow \Bbb R $, with
$$
h(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{for $|x|< \sqrt{2}$} \\
1 &\text{for $|x|>\sqrt{2}$}
\end{cases}
$$
is a continous function.

Comment: What definition of continuity do you know?

Comment: @nombre I know the definition with $ \epsilon \delta $ and one from Neighbourhoods.

Comment: Well then, given a rationnal number $x$ and a neighbourhood $W$ of $f(x)$, can you find a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ on which $f$ is constant, so that $V \subset f^{-1}(W)$?

Comment: Well I can't reach $\sqrt{2}$ so for any sequences in my Set D from $ x_n → x_0$ i would know that $ f_n → f_0$. So there has to be a neighbourhood $V$. But that's only because \sqrt{2} is not defined is it?

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that for each point $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$|x_0-x| < \delta \implies |f(x_0) - f(x)| < \epsilon. $$

It is obvious that we have continuity everywhere. The only point where things look bad is $\sqrt{2}$ but this is not a rational point.

*Hint:* You can always choose some $\delta$ such that $\delta < |x_0 - \sqrt{2}|$.

Comment: That δ would mean that $ |f(x0)−f(x)| = 0 $. But what i don't understand is that the $ \lim\limits_{x \to \sqrt2} $ from the lefthandside doesn't equal the one from the righthandside. How can that be if the function is continous?

Comment: @Agorf taking the limit to the point $\sqrt{2}$ makes no sense as this point is not in the set of rational numbers anyway. You have to show continuity only for all rational points. for the other points you did not define your function anyway

Comment: Oh that's true, i thought i could go arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{2}
$ and δ would be minimal and ϵ would be 1, which i thought disproved the continuity. I see my flaw now. Thanks mate